# Nested SQL Query from multiple tables and COUNT inline

Tags: sql, nested

Good day bloggers.

I want to create a query which will select `car name`, `model`, `price` from table `tblCars`. Within the same query result, I need to check from table `tblLikes` if certain user has liked the car. `tblLikes` has `id`, `userId` and `carId` (foreign key). So for a specific user I need something like the following in return.

```
1  Corolla Toyota  R100,000  1    (user liked)
2  A3      Audi    R700,000  0    (user did not like)
```

What Ι have tried is the following without success.

```
SELECT
     CarName
   , CarModel
   , CarPrice
   , (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tblLikes
        WHERE
                userId = @userId
            AND CarId = @CarID
    ) as Likes
FROM tblCars

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tblLikes
WHERE
        userId = @userId
    AND CarId = @CarID
```

Return `1` if the record exist and `0` if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tblCars table (
      id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , CarName varchar(20)
    , CarModel varchar(20)
    , CarPrice money
)

declare @tblLikes table (
      id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , userId int
    , carId int
)

insert into @tblCars (
      CarName
    , CarModel
    , CarPrice
)
          select 'BMW'          , 'qqq', '1000'
union all select 'Mercedes'     , 'www', '2000'
union all select 'Audi'         , 'eee', '3000'
union all select 'Scania'       , 'rrr', '4000'
union all select 'Opel'         , 'ttt', '5000'
union all select 'Mazda'        , 'yyy', '6000'
union all select 'Budatti'      , 'uuu', '7000'
union all select 'Lamborgini'   , 'iii', '8000'
union all select 'Tesla'        , 'ooo', '9000'
union all select 'Space'        , 'ppp', '10000'

insert into @tblLikes (
      userId
    , carId
)
          select '1', '1'
union all select '1', '3'
union all select '1', '5'
union all select '1', '7'
union all select '1', '9'


select
    c.*
    , (
        case when l.id is not null
            then '1'
            else '0'
        end
    ) as likes
from @tblCars as c
left outer join @tblLikes as l
    on l.carId = c.id
```